# brightway 2 multiple outputs for recycling a battery

Tags: brightway

I want to build a recycling mechanism for battiers in brightway 2. In my process of recyclying like hydrometallurgical, the result will be multiple outputs which doesnt work with brightway 2 cause of allocation. Have anyone an idea how to solve multiple outputs in brightway2 with econinvent.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think multiple outputs don't work? In the end you need to construct a system that results in a non-singular matrix, but as long as you have an alternative process that can substitute the co-products or two activities that produce the same products but in different ratios your are fine. Using Brightway 2.5 syntax:

```py
import bw2data as bd
import bw2calc as bc

bd.projects.set_current("Multifunctional")

if "Y" in bd.databases:
    del bd.databases["Y"]

db = bd.Database("Y")
db.register()

a = db.new_node(name="a", code="a")
a.save()

b = db.new_node(name="b", code="b")
b.save()

p = db.new_node(name="p", type="product", code="p")
p.save()

q = db.new_node(name="q", type="product", code="q")
q.save()

a.new_edge(input=p, amount=1, type="production").save()
a.new_edge(input=q, amount=1, type="production").save()
b.new_edge(input=q, amount=1, type="production").save()

lca = bc.LCA({p: 1})
lca.lci()
lca.supply_array
>>> array([ 1., -1.])

lca.technosphere_matrix.toarray()
>>> array([[1., 0.],
           [1., 1.]])
```

See also: [Diagonals are a social construct](https://chris.mutel.org/zero-digonals.html)

Comment: i am trying to use ellingsen et al. 2014 NCM Battery and integrate lithorec process. Everything is fine but my boss said he want to implement a lithorec recycling format. Also he said while integrating lithorec into excel sheets i will come to the problem of multiple outputs with brightway while reading sheets cause u cant have multiple outputs in sheets. He said i have to use python to fix this problem. Have u any suggestions for me how to handle that. I already have all data for lithorec process and ellingsen NCM Battery i just need to build now the sheets for lithorec. Using ecoinvent 3.8

Comment: can u explain me how the code is workin i am not getting it how to implement it in the code of using ecoinvent and brightway2. For example idk after hydrometallurgy treatment i have recovered Lithium and Cobalt how can i implement it from the recycling process as output und save it. And use that process later again as input for my comparision with recycling metalls the same battery.